# Finding if conditions in .java file

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I tried to make method which will finding all if conditions in .java file (I assume that file contain only correct if instructions).
It should count all "if", but not that which are sorrounded with comments or treaded as string.
I tried to solve this problem with StringTokenizer, but I don't know how elided line after "//" sign and strings sorrounded with " ".Is it possible to realize this problem in this way, at all?

```
public int getIfCount()
{
    int counter = 0;
    String t = "";

    try 
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(path);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        int tmp;

        while ((tmp = file.read()) != -1)
        {
            sb.append((char)tmp);
        }

        t = sb.toString();

        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(t);

        String token;


        while (stk.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            token = stk.nextToken();

             if (token.contains("/*"))
            {
                while (stk.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    if (stk.nextToken().contains("*/"))
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (token.contains("//"))
            {
                while (stk.hasMoreTokens() && stk.nextToken() != "\n")
                {
                    if (stk.nextToken().endsWith("\n"))
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (token.contains("\""))
            {
                if (!token.endsWith("\""))
                    while (stk.hasMoreTokens())
                    {
                        if(stk.nextToken().contains("\""))
                            break;
                    }
            }
            else if (token.startsWith("if"))
                counter++;
        }
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("This file does not exist!");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: To answer the question that you asked, yes, it is possible.  How would a compiler work otherwise?

Comment: I suggest you use StringBuilder as StringBuffer was deprecated more than ten years ago. Don't use `startsWith` as you might have a `iffy` token. If the code is not doing what you expect, I suggest you step through the code in your debugger.  note: you can have code in comments

Comment: To cover all border cases you will need to do a full Java lexical analysis, then count how often the keyword "if" appeared. (a border case apart from the cases you mentioned are unicode escapes. `\u0069f` is also an "if").

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is outdated too (they recommend `String.split()`) (of course you can use outdated classes if you prefer; for my part I always try to learn the new ones).

Comment: I think your use of `StringTokenizer` complicates matters (and `String.split()` would too). Some people write `if(i > 0)` while others put a space after `if`. I may even write `i++;if(i > 0)`, and `if` won’t be at the beginning of your token. Similarly in `"My string"` the quotes will come in different tokens, but in `"a"+x+"b"` you suddenly have four quotes in one token. Not to forget `\"` inside strings. I think you need some other way of splitting your input into tokens.

Answer (score 0):

No need to implement it yourself. What you are doing is implementing the basics of a parser. Although it is good to have some idea of what is going on when parsing, I suggest using a library such as https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser. Have fun.

Comment: Yes, it is... and I don't have idea how deal with that. So I need some tips what constructions I could used. Finished solution is not appropriate, I think. :( BTW. We assume that "if" have proper syntax, so only comments and different styles of programming e.g. (if() or if () etc.) are problematic.. Regex rather also not work there? :(

Comment: In that case you have to go `char` by `char` imho, to keep track of whether the potentially found `if`is also in a valid context (not a comment - multi line or not, not part of another word, be it a variable, function/method or type). Opening braces and brackets may or may not be followed by a space and then by an `if` and so forth. This is rather complicated stuff tbh. Well, I hope you get/got some inspiration. Good luck.