# count all valid if statements in .java file

Tags: java, regex, grep, match, regex-lookarounds

I need to count all valid if statements in a .java file (not commented etc)

I was trying to modify regex for commented items:

```
(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)
```

and came up with smth like this:

```
(?!(([\\(])|(/\\*)|(//)))((?=\\s*))(if)(?=[\\s\\(])
```

But it doesnt work correctly

Im using this code for test input:

```
public class Main () {
public static void main (String[] args) {

     boolean ifTrue = true;

     if (ifTrue == true) {
         String wariant = "wariant";
     } else if (ifTrue == false) {
         String dupa = "variant";
     }

     //if(ifTrue == true) {
         String wariant2 = "This is second wariant";
     //}

     if(ifTrue) {
         if(ifTrue) {

         } else if (ifTrue) {
             //if ()
             /**if*/
         }
     }

     /*if(ifTrue == true) {
         String wariant2 = "To jest wariant 2";
     }*/
  }
}
```

And this function for counting:

```
private static int countRegexInInput(String regex, String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use regex?

Comment: Commented IF is not valid IF Statement? So you have 5 valid if in your input? just counting or extracting condition and true/false parts?

Comment: Related: [Finding if conditions in .java file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608067/finding-if-conditions-in-java-file).

Comment: Maybe you can use [this strategy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) to match what you don't want but capture and count *not null* values (of group 1) like this:[`"//.*|/(?s:\\*.*?\\*)/|\\b(if[\\s(])"`](https://regex101.com/r/bEaaf0/1)

Comment: Yes, I need to use regex, its a task. Commented if is not a valid statement concerning the task. I cannot use the parser, so it is not related.

Answer (score 1):

For the current sample code , and just counting `IF` Statements:

```
/(?:^|\}\s*else)\s+\bif\b/gm
```

This regex match `IF` Statements that *seems* valid. ([SEE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uh14Z4/1))

**If your Input texts are general and complex that contains this example:**

```
    /* some comments!
     if (condition) {
     }
    */
```

use this version:*([SEE DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uh14Z4/3))*

```
(?:(?:\/\*)[^]*?\*\/|^)[\s\S]*?(?:^|\}?\s*else)\s*\bif\b
^^1 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^2   ^^^^^^3 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^4
```

Description:

1- match every thing that is `Group 2` or is new line `^`.

2- find `/*` and count capturing to `*/`

3- match and pass characters until find new `IF`

4- `IF` statement followed by one/many spaces after `^` or after `else`.

Note: this regex pattern can improve for better matching, if this is not enough!

Answer (score 0):

Well this regex seems to be working for my case:

```
([^e]\\s)(if)(\\s?\\((\\D[^\\)]+)\\))
```